# SQL Server - Dividing one column by another in a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, divide

I am seeking to make some Week On Week comparisons in a SELECT query.

The basic code will select distinct areas in the leftmost column, then the following code:

```
SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP >= GETDATE() -7 AND TIMESTAMP < GETDATE() 
            THEN ORDER_ID 
            ELSE NULL 
    END) AS THISWEEK

SELECT 
   (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP >= GETDATE() -14 AND TIMESTAMP < GETDATE() -7 
           THEN ORDER_ID 
           ELSE NULL 
    END) AS LASTWEEK
```

I'd really like to be able to have `(THISWEEK / LASTWEEK) - 1` (Like I would in excel)

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to divide Order_ID by Order_ID?  Should there be a count?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select (thisweek / lastweek) - 1
from (SELECT (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP >= GETDATE() -7 AND TIMESTAMP < GETDATE() 
                   THEN ORDER_ID 
              END) AS THISWEEK, 
            (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP >= GETDATE() -14 AND TIMESTAMP < GETDATE() -7 
                  THEN ORDER_ID 
             END) AS LASTWEEK
      from . . .
     ) t
```

It defines the variables in a subquery and then ues them.  Note that there is not any performance penalty for this; SQL Server does not "instantiate" the subquery.

Comment: This is lovely. Thank you Gordon